# How to restore only functions in windows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have taken function backup using following command:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -u username -fc  -f db_dump dbname
```

How to list the backup functions and how can I restore those functions to other database in windows?

Version is PostgreSQL 9.6.8

Comment: The pg_dump command you show is not valid.  Please show the exact command used, including case.  There is no such thing as a `function backup` with pg_dump, the closest you can get is a "--schema-only" or "--section=pre-data".

Comment: pg_dump -h hostname -U post -Fc  -s  -f db_dump1 postgredatabase

Answer (score 1):

A dump generated with the `-Fc` option of `pg_dump` is in the custom format, which implies that it has a Table of Contents, which can be used to extract contents selectively.

As explained in [pg_restore manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html), the option to output the TOC is `-l`:

```
pg_restore -l db.dump > db.list
```

This produces a file with one line per object, including functions, that can be edited manually to keep only the objects you're interested in.

Then a restore into another database could be done with:

```
  pg_restore -L db.list db.dump | psql -d otherdatabase [otheroptions]
```

If you were interested in extracting only a couple of functions, a quicker way could be to use the `-P` option to `pg_restore`:

> -P function-name(argtype [, ...]), --function=function-name(argtype [, ...])
>
> Restore the named function only. Be careful to spell the function name and arguments
>       exactly as they appear in the dump file's table of contents.